# How can i download locally the samples of the Google Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can sombebody please tell me how can i download locally the samples of the Google Drive SDK ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are available here: https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the sample repository here: https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/checkout